# Enable scrolling ouside of the main centered container

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm currently working on a dashboard and I'm having a design issue regarding the scrollbar in the content of the page.
A preview that shows the different parts of the site can be found [here](https://9gymnv.csb.app/).

Purely for design purposes, I would need to keep the current content in exactly the same position (for instance, I don't believe that resizing the components using percentages would work properly in this case) but have the scrollbar totally on the right and allow scrolling in parts that are outside of the main element. [In this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGqAl.png) the parts in green represent the areas where scrolling should be enabled.

Do I need to use JavaScript (I'm using React) and a component only for the scrollbar or can I do everything in vanilla css?

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/p75LE/2/ (should the blue component be scrollable?)

Comment: No it shouldn't be scrollable. Anyhow, I did try already something similar, but then I would have to change the whole alignment of the purple and pink components.

Comment: you can use same metod as shown on jsfiddle and add position:sticky to blue element, it will remain fixed till you scroll over parent element

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.